# How to change the label's caption using Jquery in MVC ?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am developing MVC app.

I want to change the caption of the label when I change the dropdown item.
I have Cheque,DD and RTGS opstions in the list and below code is used to show these items.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentMode, "Payment Mode")          
@Html.DropDownList("PaymentMode", new SelectList(ViewBag.PaymentModes, Model))
```

When user change the Payment mode lets say Cheque to DD then the below items label entity should change, like from Cheque No. -> DD No.

```
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChequeNo,"Cheque No.")
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChequeNo, new { style = "width:138px;" })
```

I have written the following jquery but it didnt worked. It changes the field caption not the labels caption, how to do this ?

```
  $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $('#PaymentMode').change(function () {


            $('#ChequeNo').prop('ChequeNo', 'DD No');
            var elementTitle = document.getElementById('ChequeNo').title;
            alert(elementTitle);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the label you are trying to access does not have the 'id' attribute, so you need to look for 'for' attribure of label, i.e.

```
$('label[for="ChequeNo"]').html('DD No.');
```

Hope this helps..:)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to **change the text of the label associated with the input**, if I'm correct then it's as simple as this:

```
$("#ChequeNo").prev("label").html('DD No');
```

Comment: Gets the label preceding it, it being the `ChequeNo` input. [See here](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) for the full description of `prev`.

Comment: ok, got it but previous label can be anything, cant depends on it...is any other way ?

Comment: What do you mean it can be anything? Like what?

Comment: I might be add many items in it , so each time I have to change the code...is there any other way ?

Comment: Invite me to a chat if you want to discuss this. I'm interested to know what you're up to.